# why vector's move ctor does not deduce a noexcept()?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, move-semantics

Why move constructor for `std::vector` with custom allocator does not deduce a `noexcept()` from allocator's behaviours?

This leads to the class that encapsulates such vector cannot form  the (other) vector that can be normally moved in some `<algorithm>`s. Even if the underlying type meets the nessesary requirements (MoveInsertable and DefaultInsertable).

Comment: because there might be people who might throw from a move constructor

Comment: Could you provide some code? I don't understand what you mean. The `noexcept` on what of the "allocator's behaviours"?

Comment: Say, "allocator's behaviours" means some boolean expression over `noexcept(allocator::construct(...))` and `noexcept(allocator::destroy(...))`.

Comment: @BЈовић but move constructor for vector without alternative allocator have `noexcept` at all.

Comment: and move assignment operator have `vector&operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())` form

Comment: also might be a compiler's bug

Comment: @Dukales: might be an issue with the compiler and/or the particular implementation of the standard library you have. Which version of gcc do you have ? Could you also provide the declaration of the types involved (value type and allocator) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I use *gcc 4.8* compiler (MinGW from mingw-builds project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by "move constructor for `std::vector` with custom allocator" you mean the *allocator-extended move constructor* i.e. this constructor:

```
vector(vector&& v, const allocator_type& a);
```

The main reason is that if `v.get_allocator() != a` then the constructor must allocate more memory, which could throw `bad_alloc`.  There is no way to know at compile-time if two allocators of a given type will always compare equal or not (I have reported this as a defect, see [LWG 2108](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2108)).

N.B. the standard does not require this constructor *or* the `vector(vector&&)` move constructor to be `noexcept`.

Comment: In this case, "the standard does not require" could be restated as "the standard does not allow", correct?

Comment: @mcmcc, no, that's not correct. Implementations are allowed to add or tighten exceptions specifications, so it is conforming to add `noexcept(true)` for the specializations with an allocator type that is known to always compares equal (e.g. `std::allocator`)